# audo mp3 сделать чтоб не могли скачать

Tags: javascript, php, html, mp3

есть такой вопрос
есть файл в корен сайта например test.mp3
как сделать чтоб его вставили на html audo тегу и услишали пользователи но не могли скачать его?
за акцент извините не русский

Comment: Для обычных пользователей - используя Media API,создавайте stream - его обычными средствами сохранить нельзя. Но используя специальные плагины - отдельные пользователи всёравно будут сохранять.

Comment: Спасибо а можно сделать через htaccess?

Comment: В общем случае, невозможно сделать защиту от скачивания контента, который в полной мере предоставляется клиенту тем или иным способом.

Comment: htaccess - это другая история, вы неправильно думаете, htaccess управляет исключительно правами на скачивания где скачивание = просмотр. Защиту возможно сделать исключительно используя особенности браузера, которые позволяют слушать без возможности сохранения. Допустим... браузер умеет воспроизводить life-стрим, но не умеет сохранять. Тогда создаёте такой стрим - транслируете - и 99% юзверей будут лишены возможности сохранить. Что бы не могли скачать через курл - приёдется дополнительно заморочится с кукисами или какой-то доп-проверкой.

Comment: Спасибо большое помогили мне

Comment: Если кто-то очень захочет - скачает. Можно даже просто записать звук с аудиовыхода.

Answer (score 0):

Есть хитрый вариант - конвертировать мп3 во flash с изображением собственного плеера, (или без него) а на сайте использовать это с расширением не .swf, а mp3. В итоге, это можно будет скачать, но при попытке воспроизведения в плеерах файл будет звучать с завышенной скоростью, и никто не поймет, почему.  Но вряд ли кто-то догадается, что на самом деле это файл swf а не мп3.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант хранить мп3-файлы на сервере в зашифрованном виде, и для получения возможности прослушивать нужно будет один раз ввести ключ для расшифровки. После этого он сохранится в **localStorage** и в дальнейшем можно будет свободно слушать музыку, а она будет на лету расшифровываться. Это может быть полезным так же для организации платного контента.

```
<audio id=audio src="http://opan.strana.de/encrypted-music/trewq.mp3" controls></audio>
<button onclick="localStorage.setItem('key', ''); location.reload()"> Удалить ключ </button>
<script>
if(!localStorage.getItem('key')) localStorage.setItem('key', prompt('Введите ключ'));
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", audio.src);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function(){
    let index = 0;
    let arr = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
    let mylength = arr.length;
    let out = [[], []];
    for(i = 0; i < mylength; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j < localStorage.getItem('key'); j ++){
            while(out[1][index] = false){
                index ++;
                if(index >= mylength) index = 0;
            }
            index ++;
            if(index >= mylength) index = 0;
        }   
        out[0][i] = arr[index];
        out[1][index] = false;
    }
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(out[0])]));
}
</script>
```

В этом примере ключ равен семи. (7)

Живая ссылка: [Воспроизведение зашифрованного аудиофайла](http://opan.strana.de/encrypted-music)